# Mosaic effects on iMac screen

Tags: imac, display

*not sure if this is a SuperUser question or AskDifferent question*

When I start up my iMac 21.5" (Mid 2011 model) this morning, my screen looks like this:

[image]

Then the computer is completely frozen. Is the display card going to die?

using Mac OS X 10.10.3, Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M 512 MB

Comment: Do you still have hardware-warranty?

Comment: I'm afraid the warranty expired 3 years ago ( I have 1 year warranty only )

Comment: haven't tried yet. will try if I have time later. (p.s. is there any software that I can test the display card status?)

Comment: why downvote ? please provide reasons, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking to test the video card status I believe you could restart your iMac, hold the Option key right before the chime, and choose the Recovery disk. From there you can run system diagnostics.

Comment: As my Mac is mid-2011, I should use Apple Hardware Test (AHT) instead. Will try tonight

Comment: Could you tell me what ended up happening? Same 2011 iMac problem here.